# Eclipse: refactoring functionality in Struts 2 app. Possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, refactoring

in `struts.xml` I have a list of action's.

In `.jsp` pages I have a links on actions, that described in `struts.xml`.

So, for example, I changed name for one action, on the next step - I must fix all links on all pages, I must set correct new action name.

If I have many pages - it is really hard and mmmm... stupid? job.

As IDE I use `Eclipse`.

How solution for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.  The easiest way to avoid this by far is to use the struts2-conventions-plugin, simply add the jar to your class path and it works automatically.

With it active you need to follow a structure in how you build your site, however that very small learning curve means you don't have to write any xml and you don't even need to implement an action class. Further you can use annotations to avoid writing xml at all.  It does not mean you need to remove your xml, you can use one or the other to define what you want.

See here: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/convention-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve....

Take a look at [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/wildcard-mappings.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) to carefully do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked on Struts 2, but if you always display the same list of links, i'm sure you can include a page which contains all your links? So you just have to change only one jsp.

But maybe i misunderstood your problem?

Comment: yes, it is good solution. But I try find solution related to the Eclipse.

Comment: Did you try the replace ? CTRL+H, you choose the File Search tab for example. You have a replace button.